# VBA - Expected identifier or bracketed expression error when using With command

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out an problem for class where the idea is to "shorten" the code using the With command. Below is the code I have so far. I am curious why you cannot use the shtThisSheet variable under the with command when there is a parenthesis directly after the .

Thanks all!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Formatting()
Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheet
Set shtThisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range


With shtThisSheet

    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 14
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    . ("A3:A6").Font.Bold = True
    .("A3:A6").Font.Italic = True
    .("A3:A6").Font.ColorIndex = 5
    .Range("A3:A6").InsertIndent 1
    .Range("B2:D2").Font.Bold = True
    .Range("B2:D2").Font.Italic = True
    .Range("B2:D2").Font.ColorIndex = 5
    .Range("B2:D2").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    .Range("B3:D6").Font.ColorIndex = 3
    .Range("B3:D6").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Formatting()
Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheet

Set shtThisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With shtThisSheet
    With .Range("A3:A6")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 14
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = 5
        .Range("A3:A6").InsertIndent 1
    End With
    With .Range("B2:D2")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = 5
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    With .Range("B3:D6")
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should remove the additional range call here: `.Range("A3:A6").InsertIndent 1`